# Java Junit4 Supporting extended base class

Tags: java, junit, junit4

a question:

When I do something like:

```
package path.to.common.package.test;
@BeforeClass
public class CommonTestSetup {

  public void setUp() {
   // Setup Stiff
  }
}
```

And the other class setup in the same package:

```
package path.to.common.package.test;
public class TestTest extends CommonTestSetup {
    @Test
    public void testGetTestReturnsCorrectStrings() {
    // do asserts etc
    }
}
```

And then executing JUnit test on `testGetTestReturnsCorrectStrings` I am getting an error:

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter':
  1. No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:456)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:39)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Why is that? Does it mean JUnit 4 does not support Test classes extending a base class?

The idea behind this was to create a single SetUp base class, shared by many other test classes that need it.
Originally I even tried to have the base class in another package entirely, then moved it to the same package for testing, and got a different error (the one above).

Comment: Works for me using 4.12. I had to move the @BeforeClass to the setup method and make the setup method static (was this just a mistake while copying to StackOverflow?)

Comment: First of all it is not the way it supposed to be used according to the documentation. The second - the way you posted it just wont compile.

Comment: @helospark yes I tried with `@BeforeClass`, don't remember if I kept it after moving off to a base class - will double check in the morning and let you know.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota Could you point me on the way its supposed to be used please?

Comment: @Carmageddon just follow instruction from the first comment.

Comment: @helospark You were correct! I had to do the setUp method as static - then it solved the problem. If you can do a proper answer with explanation why it doesnt work as non-static method, I'd accept that answer as the solution :)

Comment: @Carmageddon Alright, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [JUnit documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html):

> Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class

So move the `@BeforeClass` annotation to the setUp method and make into a static method.

Answer (score 54):

use import org.junit.Test;
instead of import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

Comment: you are a life saver my friend.. thanks, this worked

Answer (score 0):

You may also check for things like

```
class classname {
  class another class{
  }
}
```

*Keep one class in file it helps*
I experienced similar ... I hopes it help someone ;-)